# javascript function and foreach scopes

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issue with the js strange scope behaviour.
I have this `Graph` function (a simple wrapper of  https://github.com/cpettitt/graphlib). If I add nodes one by one like I do with the node labeled "1" all works, if I use a forEach I have a scope problem.

```
function Graph() {
    this.g = new graphlib.Graph();
    this.setNode = function (id, value) {
        this.g.setNode(id, value || {}); 
    }
}

var gg = new Graph();
    gg.setNode("1"); //works

    ["2a","2b"].forEach(gg.setNode); //doesn't work
```

The error is `Cannot read property 'g' of undefined` the `g` instance var of `Graph` isn't visible in that forEach.

Comment: No, the error means that `this` is `undefined` (you are trying to access the property `g` on `this` (`this.g`), "Cannot read property 'g' of undefined" therefore means that `this` is `undefined`). While `this` and "scope" are related, the problem is with `this`, not the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second argument to `forEach` to lock the function call to a scope:

```
["2a","2b"].forEach(gg.setNode, gg);
```

Comment: `this` and scope are related but not the same.

Comment: it works. Ates Goral and @Felix Kling could you provide some references/articles about the unusual js this/scope stuff?

Comment: @alfredopacino: See the duplicate question.